# How can I update reviews and rating on Magento Marketplace?

Tags: extensions, review, marketplace

I purchased one product(extension in my case) from Magento marketplace and tried to implement that extension with my Magento website.

But unfortunately that is not working any more. I have given 2 star rating to that product and also asked an query to support portal for same.

They guys read my query and replied me within 12 hours and after some conversation within support staff, they found that issue is within extension.

They resolved that issue and now, I am very happy with the extension.

Now, I want to give 5 star rating on my previous 2 star rating. Is it possible as I can give 5 star rating and can update review text also?

Thank you,

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think there is no direct way to update review on Marketplace, you should throw an email to `marketplace@magento.com`  and tell your story, they will help you with this or create an Internal ticket for you